# Restart application after Android kills it

Tags: android, android-manifest

As far as I know, Android kills an application after sometime if the
user is not interacting with it, in order to save memory. If the user
goes back to the application, the last activity is displayed again.
What I would like to do is that when this situations occurs, I always
would like to restart from my main activity. But only if my
application was killed, not in other scenarios.

Is there any way to do that? in the manifest for example?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check whether an Activity has been resumed by checking if the bundle in the `onCreate` method is null:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null)
```

If it isn't null, your activity has been resumed from being killed.

If you're simply pausing your activity `onResume()` is called over `onCreate()`.

See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for the Activity Lifecycle.
[image]

Comment: but that implies that I have to check that in every activity I have, right? It's a good idea, thanks. I'll try to find something more general, but I think yours can help

Comment: If you want to do this for every activity simply create a class which extends Activity, add the code to reset it in the onCreate() which calls super, then extend every one of your Activities from your modified class (They already call super so everything will pan out great).

Comment: What if you rotate the activity? its recreated and bundle will not be null